# JavaFxPorts - javafx.platform is not defined

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I am trying to run the sample project of the gluon plugin created in Netbeans 8.2. But I am handling with some errors I can't fix. Maybe you can help me with my problems?

When I execute the Gluon Application in Netbeans, i get the warning:

```
SERIOUS: javafx.platform is not defined. Desktop will be assumed by default.
```

I also tried to install it on my phone. The error message ist:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:

ANDROID_HOME not specified. Either set it as a gradle property, a system environment variable or directly in your build.gradle by setting the extension jfxmobile.android.androidSdk.


* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 10s
```

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: See https://docs.gluonhq.com/getting-started/#android-support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is defined in this line:

`ANDROID_HOME not specified. Either set it as a gradle property, a system environment variable or directly in your build.gradle by setting the extension jfxmobile.android.androidSdk.`

You just have to specify the path to the Android SDK that you installed on your system.  this has to be giving when you run any of your client commands: client: build; client:run and so on.  Try these steps

1. Open up your navigation pane.
2. Click on the name of your project and you should see a list of Goals that you can run towards build and deployment concerning your project

[List of Goals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG27j.png)

3. Click Add and select Add New Environment Variable.  This will give you the screen to add the path to your android_sdk installation to the build path. Once you press okay, the Goal will automatically begin processing.  Just remember to do this when you perform a client:run or client:? -

[Add SDK Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5ZVb.png) ****